# HTTPS POST working on Gingerbread but not on Froyo?

Tags: android, https, http-post

Here's a section of code in question:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(strName1, strValue1));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(strName2, strValue2));
post = new HttpPost(strPostURL);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(post);
```

strPostURL begins with "https://".

This code fails on the last line - throws the following exception:

```
WARN/System.err(7151): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
WARN/System.err(7151): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
```

I've tried this code against both Froyo (2.2) and Gingerbread (2.3.3) platform and it only works on 2.3.3. Same results on emulators as well.

When I tried the regular HTTP POST on my test server, both Froyo and Gingerbread works fine, so there must be something particular about HTTPS that is causing this issue.

If matters, I am also using httpmime-4.1.2.jar for handling multi-part attachments at a later part of the code, so this jar is included in my build path.

Could someone kindly point out what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: What happens if you open this URL in browser on those devices?

Comment: Both devies show the expected pages. Of course, there is a difference from the above code, since I am only typing the URLs manually so this is no longer a POST call.